# Netflix is not loading properly in chrome on mac with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for most requests

Tags: google-chrome, netflix

Every time I try to load netflix on chrome I get an almost empty black and white page. It seems all assets on the webpage are failing to load with an  ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

It works fine on Safari (intermittently) but not on FF or Chrome. It also works on other macs in the house using chrome except for one. This one. The weirdest part is that it works fine (on chrome) when I connect to another wifi network.
I already tried clearing all cookies and caches, cookies and history, updated the browser, tried incognito, disabled extensions and removed chrome and reinstalled it, removed all google files from mac. The pictures below illustrate what's going on.[image] 
[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's working on other machines and browsers on the same network, it's certainly a local problem and not a problem with using the functionality of the site. You really should ask at [su].

Comment: I was able to fix it by renewing DHCP lease on the wifi network. I did not know which site to ask. Please feel free to move the question to super user. I could not do it.

Comment: i take that back. I still don't know what's going on.

Comment: I voted to migrate, but it requires more people who agree. You can flag it for moderator attention and ask that it be migrated.